# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when trying to create column in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using the following code for create a column in an existing table, but, I'm getting this error:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

I've tried get the desired result *(create column in table "only if this column does not exists")* without the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`  instruction, but, PL/SQL doesn't allow use the `ALTER TABLE [...]` in an `IF [] THEN` structure.

Is there something I'm missing?

*This is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70414e9b3212e1d902ac0cc76100f70f) sample*:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE" 
>    (  "ID_TABLE" NUMBER(9,0)
>    ) ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
> CLEAR SCREEN;
> DECLARE 
>   V_COLUMN_EXISTS NUMBER := 0;
> BEGIN
>   SELECT COUNT(1) CONTEO 
>   INTO V_COLUMN_EXISTS 
>   FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
>   WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'PNT_NCODE' 
>   AND UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE';
>   
>   IF V_COLUMN_EXISTS = 0 THEN 
>     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE ADD PNT_NCODE NUMBER (9,0) ' || 
>     ' COMMENT ON COLUMN TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE.PNT_NCODE IS ''Stores ID from TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE_2.''';
>   ELSE 
>     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column already exists');
>   END IF;
>   
> END;
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you have `set serveroutput on` and `clear screen` in your script.  db<>fiddle knows how to interpret SQL and PL/SQL.  It doesn't support `SQL*Plus` commands.

If you remove those, the next error you'll get is that you have a single `execute immediate` statement that is trying to execute two separate statements.  Creating the column and adding a comment on the column are separate operations so you need separate statements.

If I change your [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e0e78a1f7c9876cb65ee9b5e182e2cce) to this, it works the way you want

```
DECLARE 
  V_COLUMN_EXISTS NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) CONTEO 
  INTO V_COLUMN_EXISTS 
  FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
  WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'PNT_NCODE' 
  AND UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE';
  
  IF V_COLUMN_EXISTS = 0 THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE ADD PNT_NCODE NUMBER (9,0) '; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMENT ON COLUMN TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE.PNT_NCODE IS ''Stores ID from TMP_TABLE_SAMPLE_2.''';
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column already exists');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Excellent!, thank you, Justin! - out of curiosity, do you know why `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` does not accept a string (*in the way I tried in my question*)?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes - `execute immediate` takes a SQL statement or a PL/SQL statement.  A string with two separate SQL statements is neither of those.